# Custom parser for HTML5 and other languages

Tags: html, parsing, token, lexical-analysis

I'm attempting to write my very own custom parser (in C#) for (X)HTML5 and whatever might be embedded (EcmaScript, CSS) - just to learn and have fun. Although I'm an intermediate programmer I don't know much about parsers and all the technical stuff. I am able to create a lexical analyser (tokeniser) for HTML5 fairly easily but the syntactical analysis (parsing) is a bit tricky. I'm not sure if I should first lexically analyse all the source input and then do the other or try both at the same time; get char until I have a token, realise what the token syntactially means and then expect a certain token relevant to the previous one. The problem that I face is that HTML might have other languages such as CSS and JavaScript embedded and they, as far as I can see, will have different categories of tokens, so I'm not sure how to "know" where I am in the code as I tokenise it in order to have varying definitions of what a token "is". Any thoughts? Also, what are the benefits/drawbacks of analysing lexically first and then syntactically vs. doing both in at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is purely for your own education regarding parsing, I would suggest tacking a much smaller / easier field than HTML , CSS and JS parsing as HTML and JS both represent some really quite nasty parsing problems which even the most experienced parser writer would feel nervous tackling.

A language based off Scheme or Basic would probably be my first pick.
(A personal favourite is building a parser / interpreter as I go through http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-10.html )

(Also picking up a copy of something like Modern Complier Design probably wouldn't hurt: [http://www.amazon.com/Modern-Compiler-Design-D-Grune/dp/0471976970](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471976970) )

If it has to be web related in order to keep your interest, I'd take a stab at doing your parser for one of the smaller web related languages such as sass ( http://sass-lang.com )

On the other hand, if this is something work related where you really need to parse those specific things, I'd suggest skipping the effort of writing your own parser entirely and hook into something like the Razor or Chromium libraries.

And to directly answer at least the second half of your question: I would recommend always splitting the various phases of parsing / interpreting out as far as possible from each other.

Each problem is difficult enough on it's own without trying to be "too smart" and attempting to combine functionality into a single sweep.

Where ever possible I'd suggest keeping things as high level, abstract and "clean" as possible... thus construct a tree of nodes specifically for lexical parsing and another for syntactical parsing... and in the case of combined languages as HTML, CSS and JS, a different AST and parsing code for each.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's just educational. If you need to come to this website to ask basic questions about something that you're building at work you probably should resign. Separating the two sounds good to me. I guess I'll just have to make token categories that work for all even though some of them wouldn't be used for certain purposes - for example I can't think of a single token in HTML that starts with a digit although a JavaScript variable value might. I doesn't have to be web related to keep me interested but making a parser for C# sounds much harder and I've never heard of SASS.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great course on `Udacity` [1] called `Programming Languages` that covers the full concept of HTML and Javacript processing .

It covers in depth the lexical analysis, parsing and interpretation . It only covers a subset of Javascript so you have further development ahead of you after you finish the course, but you will have acquired the general structure and the concepts .

[1] http://www.udacity.com/overview/Course/cs262/CourseRev/apr2012

Comment: Cool, a course about building a web browser. Sounds very interesting and challenging.